# How to download the video from amazon if the acl is set private

Tags: php, amazon-s3

In my website user has an option to download the video after buying the video. Videos i have saved in amazon s3. I have made the files private(for security before buying) in amazon s3. I tried to give the option where the user can download the files from signed urls.. here user will be able to download the video form signed urls only if the file is public in amazon. If its private it says cant render the file.

Is ther any way to download the files if the ACL is private? Or how do i change the ACL IN That page only for a single(that) file to public?

or any other solution in php? its very urgent???

any help is appreciable....

thanks in advance....

Comment: CAPSLOCK is just like shouting at people. this won't lead to getting any better or faster answers - you just annoy people who _could_ help you.

Comment: Why are people voting to close? it's a perfectly reasonable question...

Comment: @bdonlan The title was in all caps and the last 4 lines as well.

Comment: @gnur, ah, well, that's no reason to close a question, is it? Downvote, sure, edit, sure, but that's an abuse of the close function if you ask me :/

Comment: @bdonlan, I agree, I didn't downvote, I edited :)

Answer (score 1):

The signed url should work on private files, i have made a similar system which emails people signed urls to private files and they work perfectly.
Another way would be to fetch files from S3 to your server and then let the user download it from there, but its not very elegant.

Comment: and @bdonlan are right: A pre-signed URL is the solution to your problem. If you're getting errors, then it's an error in the software you're using to generate the pre-signed URL. I'm not sure which language you're using, but Amazon provides *working* SDKs for Java, C#, PHP, iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

Signed URLs can access files with all the rights of the key used to sign the URL. So as long as you sign using an access ID with access to the file, you can download it even if it's private. This is in fact the primary intended use of signed URLs, so don't worry about it too much.